# Why do Darkseid and Orion look so different if they're father and son?

Tags: comics, dc

Orion has a very human appearance.

[image]

[image]

And Darkseid looks like this.

[image]

Has this ever been explained?

Edit: I remembered that in Kingdom Come we see an older Orion whose appearance more closely resembles Darkseid, but, still, pretty different.

[image]

Comment: Considering Orion's half-brothers [Kalibak](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Kalibakdcu0.jpg) and [Grayven](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a5/Grayvendcu1.jpg) look much more like Darkseid, it probably has a lot to do with who Orion's mother is. AFAIK, that isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Orion has sort of "hulked out" on occasion, and the resemblance to Darkseid is more pronounced then. Also, I think his Mother Box is involved in his appearance; it may be a front to help him fit in on New Genesis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orion possesses a [Mother Box](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Box).  A Mother Box (or the Apokalyptian Father Box) is a tool used by the New Gods.  They are sentient and sapient living computers.  They can open Boom Tubes, heal the injured, manipulate energy, and many other effects (similar in some ways to a Green Lantern Power Ring, but more so).  Orion's Mother Box constantly works to suppress his rage and also cloaks him in an illusion that is closer to the New Genesis form.  His normal form has Darkseid's gray skin, red eyes, and a blockier facial structure.

Here's a panel which shows him in the early stages of reverting to his natural form[image]:

Comment: Well, actually, I don't think his skin is naturally grey, but otherwise right.

Comment: replaced your image with a better one. +1 from me!

Comment: Cool and also kinda sad

Comment: It's also the case that Darkseid didn't always look gray, before he bonded with the Omega Force, he looked much more human when he was Uxas.

Answer (score 3):

There's a possibility he's not actually Darkseid's son

> Orion was told by his mother, Tigra, that he was not in fact that son of Darkseid, but one of his captains. Tigra also tells Orion that had she not told Darkseid that she was carrying his son, then Darkseid would have undoubtedly killed Tigra for committing adultery. [source](http://www.comicvine.com/orion/4005-2363/)
>
> Long after Tigra had her son Orion, she claimed he was not Darkseid's son. Tigra stated how she only told him she was pregnant to save her own life, knowing Darkseid wouldn't turn down an heir. In this telling, she says she was never truley pregnant when she told this to Darkseid, so she met with a captian of the Imperial Guard. She says the only thing that mattered was that he was handsome and willing. [source](http://www.comicvine.com/tigra/4005-55609/)

But if he is Darkseid's biological son, his mother looks pretty [*normal*](http://www.comicvine.com/tigra/4005-55609/). So he could have inherited his looks from her.